# Firebase's AngularFire Authentication $onAuth throwing "Undefined is not a function"

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to upgrade an application to the new Firebase Authentication methods. I've got most things working, but for some reason when I try this.

```
myApp.controller('StatusController', function(
  $scope, $rootScope,
    $location, $firebase, $firebaseAuth, FIREBASE_URL) {

  $scope.logout = function() {
    Authentication.logout();
    $location.path('/login');
  } //logout

  $rootScope.$onAuth(function(authUser) {
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/users/' + authUser.uid);
    var user = $firebase(ref).$asObject();

    user.$loaded().then(function() {
      $rootScope.currentUser = user;
    });
  }); //login

  $rootScope.$on('logout', function(e, authUser) {
    $rootScope.currentUser = null;
  }); //login

}); //StatusController
```

I'm getting a "undefined is not a function", even when I just try the example on the site. I'm not sure why this is happening. Just for reference, this controller keeps track of the authentication in order to update the site navigation.

```
<header>
  <nav class="cf" ng-include="'views/nav.html'"
    ng-controller="StatusController"></nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the docs you're referencing?

Comment: Here's the AngularFire docs. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-user-authentication-and-management-onauthcallback-context

Comment: Here's the project as it stands on github. https://github.com/planetoftheweb/angulardata/tree/auth_update

Comment: Are you sure you are using the most recent version of AngularFire? IIRC onAuth is a relatively recent addition.

Comment: Yep...this is using angularfire 0.9.0

Comment: $onAuth does not exist on $rootScope. Nothing in the docs suggests this would be possible so I'm a bit baffled why you would expect it to exist there. Try following [the auth guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-angular-authentication).

Answer (score 3):

you can fix the problem like this, ideally you would use $rootScope but this way it works too without the use of $rootScope as it seems Firebase staff implemented $onAuth in a rootScope-like way.

As an example to your application:

```
myApp.controller('StatusController', function($scope,$firebase,$firebaseAuth,FIREBASE_URL) {
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

    auth.$onAuth(function(authData){
        console.log(authData);
        $scope.userStatus = authData.password.email;
    }); // Check user status 
}); // StatusController
```

PS: authData.password.email only inserts the email address to the $scope.userStatus.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the $onAuth function with $timeout so it processes in the digest loop!

```
// wrap the $onAuth function with $timeout so it processes
    // in the digest loop.
    onAuth: function onLoggedIn(callback) {
      auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
        $timeout(function() {
          callback(authData);
        });
      });
    }
```

Comment: would you please care to take a look at this similar question I had: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872935/firebase-authwithoauthredirect-doesnt-call-onauth-without-page-refresh